# How to load setting values from a Java properties file?

Tags: sbt

Is there a way for me to dynamically load a setting value from a properties file?

I mean, instead of hardcoding into `build.sbt`

```
name := "helloWorld"
```

Have some `application.properties` file with

```
name=helloWorld
```

And then, in the `build.sbt` file, have `name := application.properties["name"]`
(last example is purely schematic, but I hope the idea was clear)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can create a setting key which holds properties read from a file.

```
import java.util.Properties

val appProperties = settingKey[Properties]("The application properties")

appProperties := {
  val prop = new Properties()
  IO.load(prop, new File("application.properties"))
  prop
}

name := appProperties.value.getProperty("name")
```

Answer (score 8):

Cheating a bit on the answer from @daniel-olszewski.

In `project/build.sbt` declare dependency on [Typesafe Config](https://github.com/typesafehub/config):

```
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe" % "config" % "1.2.1"
```

In `build.sbt` load properties using Typesafe Config and set settings:

```
import com.typesafe.config.{ConfigFactory, Config}

lazy val appProperties = settingKey[Config]("The application properties")

appProperties := {
  ConfigFactory.load()
}

name := {
  try {
    appProperties.value.getString("name")
  } catch {
    case _: Exception => "<empty>"
  }
}
```

You could define a `def` that would set values from the properties, too.

Comment: I tried this approach but apparently the config then is empty. If I do the same in my application it works fine.