# Access object both from build.sbt and application code

Tags: scala, sbt

I need to access a `build.sbt` variable from application code, or define some class/object accessible both from the `build.sbt` and the application code. How to do this?

For example,
`build.sbt`:

```
propName := "hello"
```

`MyApp.scala`:

```
buildSbtProvider.getVariable("propName")
```

Or
`build.sbt`:

```
propName := CommonObject.hello
```

`MyApp.scala`:

```
propName = CommonObject.hello
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possibility would be to use the default `src/main/resources/application.conf` file. This file is often used to set properties for the application at run time. And just discovered you can read it from build.sbt (see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25667334/9297144))

So let's say this application.conf has this content:

```
{ name=my_app_name }
```

Then you can get the name from within build.sbt:

```
import java.util.Properties

val appProperties = settingKey[Properties]("The application properties")

appProperties := {
  val prop = new Properties()
  IO.load(prop, new File("src/main/resources/application.conf"))
  prop
}

name := appProperties.value.getProperty("name")
```

On the application side, this is very classic:

```
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory

var conf = ConfigFactory.load

println(conf.getString("name"))
```

Answer (score 8):

You may want to use the [`sbt-buildinfo`](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-buildinfo) plugin for this.

As stated in the documentation, you just have to add a few definition to your build

```
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).
  enablePlugins(BuildInfoPlugin).
  settings(
    buildInfoKeys := Seq[BuildInfoKey](name, version, scalaVersion, sbtVersion),
    buildInfoPackage := "hello"
  )
```

And this would generate the following class that you can use after reload:

```
package hello

import java.io.File
import java.lang._
import java.net.URL
import scala._; import Predef._

/** This object was generated by sbt-buildinfo. */
case object BuildInfo {
  /** The value is "helloworld". */
  val name: String = "helloworld"
  /** The value is "0.1-SNAPSHOT". */
  val version: String = "0.1-SNAPSHOT"
  /** The value is "2.10.3". */
  val scalaVersion: String = "2.10.3"
  /** The value is "0.13.2". */
  val sbtVersion: String = "0.13.2"
  override val toString: String = "name: %s, version: %s, scalaVersion: %s, sbtVersion: %s" format (name, version, scalaVersion, sbtVersion)
}
```

You can refer to the [README](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-buildinfo/blob/master/README.markdown) file of the project for more details.